# How do I change laravel mail body?

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-mail

I used laravel default `Auth` to learn laravel by using `php artisan make:auth`. Where I also used default mailing of laravel.

I want to know about mailing process. I able to send `password reset` mail. But I want to change this default mail format. Where I can change this or how?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passwords#password-customization

Comment: php artisan vendor:publish it will publish the views and you can modify them

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can modify your laravel mail body view from:

```
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Notifications/resources/views/email.blade.php
```

But if you want to change some text information then see below page:

```
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Notifications/ResetPassword.php
```

Comment: If anyone stumbles upon this do not edit vendor files directly. When the app is deployed the vendor folder is regenerated. Instead, to edit the mail, publish the mail markdown and modify them there. This will save a big headache!

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mail#customizing-the-components